# virtual subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

i want this:

http://100.mydomain.ir    --->    http://mydomain.ir?option=user&id=100

i try this, but do not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).mydomain.ir$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).mydomain.ir$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.ir$ [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?option=user&id=%2 [R=301,L]
```

what is my correct .htaccess code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to achieve this.

Comment: hi, i use it
RewriteEngine on